# How can I insert values in a table with foreign keys in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have the following table full of information imported from a csv file:

```
create table movie (

    title,
    id_director int references director (id_director),
    duration int,
    gross int,
    budget int,
    id_movie serial,
    primary key (id_movie)
);
```

Now I want to add another row executing this `INSERT`

```
insert into movie (title, id_director, duration, gross, budget)
values ("Movie example", 1, 210, 50000, 2000);
```

But as an output I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`movies`.`movie`, CONSTRAINT `movie_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`id_director`) REFERENCES `director` (`id_director`))

Looks like I can't add information to the table the way I did because the table contain foreign keys...

How can I insert data into this table then?

Comment: This means that you don't have a director with `id = 1`.

Comment: You cannot have a chicken until you have an egg! Or is that the other way round :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Who knows ;) Thanks! I now understand the problem